# Flickering strokes when changing stroke depth order to 3D location in Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil, brushes, draw-mode

Hello Blender Community,

When I change the stroke depth order to 3D location, strokes drawn with a brush that has opacity appear to flicker depending on the viewing angle. Is there any solution or workaround to fix it?

[image]

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are encountering may be **Z-Fighting**. It is typically caused by overlap. Grease pencil objects are most effective when used in *2D Layers*. Therefore, the reason you are encountering this problem is most likely because you switched to *3D Location*. In 3D space, your grease pencil object will encounter similar problems that other 3D-objects face.

A quick fix is to adjust the `Clip Start` of your view to a bigger value.

[image]

If this doesn't work, then you may need to share an example file using https://blend-exchange.com/. To determine the actual reason for your flickering or provide an in-depth solution would require more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Unfortunately, the Clip Start method didn't work well in my side :(

I have deleted the blender data using for the original post, but I have made the same file has the same problem. 
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Kb8dnrOS" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Kb8dnrOS/)

I understood the grace pencil is made for making 2D animation, but I want to make a hand-drawn 3D artwork, so It would be great if there are some tricks or something to avoid this issue.

Comment: Ah, now I see what is happening in your file. It was not any of the settings, but the Air brush that you were using that caused the flickering. That brush has always been problematic. I've rarely seen anyone use it because of the issues it causes. I think the work around would be create your own custom Air brush with the opacity settings.